# Change SelectionMode in a DataGridView from RowHeaderSelect to ColumnHeaderSelect

Tags: c#

I fill my DataGridView from a DataTable. My DataGridView has the SelectionMode RowHeaderSelect, but I now want to change it to ColumnHeaderSelect.

But when I change the property I get an exception.
**My Code so for the RowHeaderSelect:**
How I create my Datatable:

```
values = new string[numbersOfRows, numbersOfColumns]; //is filled in a different part in the code

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfColumns; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(values[0, i]);
}

for (int j = 2; j < numbersOfRows; j++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfColumns; i++)
    {
        row[i] = values[j,i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

How I create my DataGridView:

```
dgv_schedule.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; //In this line I get my exception when I change 
                                          //the SelectionMode from RowHeaderSelect to 
                                          //ColumnHeaderSelect
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?
exception: System.InvalidOperationException and I work with WinForms

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) this exception is generated when the `SortMode` of one or more of the columns is set to `Automatic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding this code:

```
dgv_schedule.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; //Selection mode is RowHeaderSelect

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
{
    dgv_schedule.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
}
dgv_schedule.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
```